# Python PyGame Image.png is not displaying

Tags: python, image, pygame

I ran into a problem that if I run my project it is not showing the image the image is very big so I resized it and it was not helping.
The Code:

```
import pygame
import sys

def title(title):
    pygame.display.set_caption(title)

def background(Color1, Color2, Color3):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (Color1, Color2, Color3), pygame.Rect(0, 0, 2000, 3000))
    pygame.display.flip()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
Card1Img = pygame.image.load('Card1.png')
Card1Img = pygame.transform.scale(Card1Img, (100,100))

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit(0)

    background(255, 255, 255)
    title("Card-Jitsu")
    screen.blit(Card1Img, (0, 0))
```

The Image is 1000 x 1126 px:
[image]
I did just want to make a copy of Card-Jitsu in python and pygame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the display is not updating and drawing the image. You need to have the display update at the end of your while loop. The below code should work:

```py
import pygame
import sys

def title(title):
    pygame.display.set_caption(title)

def background(Color1, Color2, Color3):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (Color1, Color2, Color3), pygame.Rect(0, 0, 2000, 3000))
    #Having the display update here causes flickering
    

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
Card1Img = pygame.image.load('Card1.png')
Card1Img = pygame.transform.scale(Card1Img, (100,100))

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit(0)

    background(255, 255, 255)
    title("Card-Jitsu")
    screen.blit(Card1Img, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip() #update the display after the image and background have been drawn
```